# C: Dynamic Array and Pointer array creates Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Hello i'm trying to create a program in C, which should read Values from another file and display them in another file with some exceptions. The problem i'm getting is a segmentation fault which occurs when i'm trying to read a part of my result-array which is empty. My For-loop scans a file for every line and if a line in this particular file matches my needs, it's values should get saved in an array. This array should be printed in a 2nd .txt file. I wanted to printf some values of my array for testing purposes. I guess it's a mistake in my arrays or pointers.

```
/* Die Konstanten:
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_STR - die maximale String Länge
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_ARR - die maximale Array Länge
 *  sind input3.c auf jeweils 255 und 100 definiert
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        if (argc < 3) {
            printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
            printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
            printf("Klein-/Großschreibung beachten!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
        char *bundesland = argv[2];

// Statisch allokierter Speicher
char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

// Hier implementieren
int j;
char** result = (char *) malloc (MAX_LAENGE_ARR * sizeof(char));
if (result == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed while allocating memory");
    exit(1);
    } 
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0 && *bewohner > anzahl) {
        result[i] = malloc(MAX_LAENGE_STR * sizeof(char));
        if (result == NULL) {
            perror("malloc failed while allocating memory");
            exit(1);
        }
        snprintf(result[i], MAX_LAENGE_ARR, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
        //printf("%s\n", result[i]);
    }
} 
printf("%s", result[0]);
// Mithilfe von write_file(...) soll das Ergebnis in die "resultat.txt"
// geschrieben werden. 
write_file(result, len);
// Dynamisch allozierter Speicher muss hier freigegeben werden.
```

}

Comment: `result` is defined as `char **` but you are allocating as `char` and casting to `char *`. Don't cast the return value of malloc in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating to `result` incorrectly. You are allocating `MAX_LAENGE_ARR*sizeof(char)` bytes. You need to allocate `MAX_LAENGE_ARR*sizeof(char *)` bytes. Also you are casting the return  value of `malloc` to the wrong type. If you compile with warnings on, the compiler should have caught this error. But, you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
char** result = malloc (MAX_LAENGE_ARR * sizeof(*result));
```

Also, I think you need to replace  `MAX_LAENGE_ARR` with `MAX_LAENGE_STR` in the following line:

```
snprintf(result[i], MAX_LAENGE_ARR, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
```